# Output mysql error log both to file and to stderr

Tags: mysql, docker, logging, mysql-5.7

Mysql (running in docker) by default logs to stderr, because there isn't configured parameter `--log_error`

If you run mysql with the aforementioned parameter, it will log to file as expected

```
docker run -ti --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest --log_error=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.error.log
```

What I would like to do is to have both logging to stderr and to the file (3rd party app reads the file and I'd like to be able to read the logs using `docker logs` command). Is there some way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Add option `--log-timestamps` :

```bash
docker run \
    -ti \
    --name some-mysql \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw \
    -d \
    mysql:latest \
    --log_error=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.error.log \
    --log-timestamps=SYSTEM
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question at all